# My docker-compose is running, but I cannot reach from host

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, elk

Here it is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    build:
      context: elasticsearch/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: volume
        source: elasticsearch
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: changeme
      # Use single node discovery in order to disable production mode and avoid bootstrap checks.
      # see: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/bootstrap-checks.html
      discovery.type: single-node
    networks:
      - elk

  logstash:
    build:
      context: logstash/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/config/logstash.yml
        target: /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/pipeline
        target: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
        read_only: true
    ports:
      - "5044:5044"
      - "5000:5000/tcp"
      - "5000:5000/udp"
      - "9600:9600"
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  kibana:
    build:
      context: kibana/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./kibana/config/kibana.yml
        target: /usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
        read_only: true
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  zookeeper:
    image: strimzi/kafka:0.11.3-kafka-2.1.0
    container_name: zookeeper
    command: [
      "sh", "-c",
      "bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties"
    ]
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    networks:
      - elk
    environment:
      LOG_DIR: /tmp/logs

  kafka:
    image: strimzi/kafka:0.11.3-kafka-2.1.0
    command: [
      "sh", "-c",
      "bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties --override listeners=$${KAFKA_LISTENERS} --override advertised.listeners=$${KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS} --override zookeeper.connect=$${KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT}"
    ]
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    networks:
      - elk
    environment:
      LOG_DIR: "/tmp/logs"
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181

networks:
  elk:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  elasticsearch:
```

And here it is my logstash.conf file:

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "kafka:9092"
    topics => "results"
    codec => json { charset => "UTF-8" }
    }
}
filter {
    date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
        user => "elastic"
        password => "changeme"
        ecs_compatibility => disabled
    }
}
```

I can send a message to a result topic, but nor I can see this message inside container neither I can produce any message inside container. What is wrong here ? If I can make connection, this message will go throug logstash anyway ?

Comment: Unclear what you're trying to reach from the host and the Strimzi images are generally supposed to be used and configured via kubernetes, so are you sure those environment variables are doing the right thing?

Comment: And what command are you using to try to consume the messages from Kafka in the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092`

Kafka clients in the Docker network cannot reach your broker if you only advertise localhost.

Plus, I'm not sure that the Strimzi image even uses those variables - [source](https://github.com/strimzi/strimzi-kafka-operator/blob/master/docker-images/kafka/scripts/kafka_config_generator.sh#L44)

You can use the `confluentinc/cp-kafka` image as discussed [in this post](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/) with slight modification to those variables, or if you have something against that, you can use Bitnami or wurstmeister containers, which each have their own individual environment variables for those settings

Comment: I solved my problem by using Bitnami. It has very clear documentation. Thank you for support

Comment: I broke those dead-ends :) they are approximately all about the same problem that I confronted. I've removed them.